# Add vector to Matrix in Opencv

Tags: opencv, matrix, vector

I have a question like this, ex:
I have a vector =

```
[1, 2, 3]
```

I have a matrix =

```
[1, 2, 3]
[4, 5, 6]
[7, 8, 9]
```

expected result is:

```
[1+1, 2+2, 3+3]
[4+1, 5+2, 6+3]
[7+1, 8+2, 9+3]
```

it is to "add vector (or row) to matrix".

Is there an API or convenient way? 
ps: I am coding in C++.

Answer (score 2):

You can't add a vector to a matrix. 
You can add matrix and scalar or matrix and matrix.
To do what you want, you can add your row matrix to each row of your 3x3 matrix :

```
unsigned char values[9] = { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 };
cv::Mat matrix(3,3,CV_8UC1, values);
unsigned char rowval[3] = { 1,2,3 };
cv::Mat rowmat(1,3,CV_8UC1, rowval);

std::cout << "input:\n";
std::cout << matrix << "\n";
std::cout << "rowmat:\n";
std::cout << rowmat << "\n";

for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
  matrix.row(i) += rowmat;

std::cout << "result:\n";
std::cout << matrix << "\n";
```

Which outputs:

```
input:
[  1,   2,   3;
   4,   5,   6;
   7,   8,   9]
rowmat:
[  1,   2,   3]
result:
[  2,   4,   6;
   5,   7,   9;
   8,  10,  12]
```

Answer (score 0):

There is now straightfoward way of doing this. The two of many approaches I can think of are: mat addition and subsequent col addition.

Mat addition:

```
cv::Mat a = (cv::Mat_<uchar>(3, 3) << 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9);
cv::Mat b = (cv::Mat_<uchar>(3, 3) << 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3);
cv::Mat r = a + b;
```

Per col addition:

```
std::vector s{1,2,3};
for (int col = 0; col < a.cols; ++col)
{
   a.col(col) += s[col];
}
```